# Liquid Vapour Surface Tension Interaction with Solid

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, surface-tension

In my book there's an experiment to calculate the value of surface tension in which a solid of certain weight is kept on the surface of a liquid and it remains in equilibrium . Now the book states that the force which is responsible for the equilibrium of the solid is the surface tension of liquid-air interface.
[image]
My doubt is :
how is liquid-air interface surface tension force responsible for the equilibrium of the solid kept on the surface of a liquid? Like, how this force even interacts with the solid?

Answer (score 1):

There are three interfaces in this problem: liquid-air, liquid-solid, and solid-air. Each interface has a corresponding surface tension $\gamma_{LA}$, $\gamma_{SL}$, $\gamma_{SA}$. For example, the [contact angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle) between the surface of a liquid and the surface of a solid depends on all three of these quantities. Force is related to energy. Zero force at the point of stable equilibrium corresponds to a minimum of energy. Thus, the stable equilibrium of a solid body in this problem is determined by the minimum of the sum of the three boundary surface energies and the energy of the solid body, liquid and air in the gravitational field.

Update. What is said in the book means that when the vertical position of a solid body changes by $\Delta z$, the area of the liquid-air interface changes by $-2l\Delta z$, and the areas of the liquid-solid and solid-air interfaces do not change. Therefore, the change in energy is $\Delta U = -S_{la}2l\Delta z$ and the vertical force associated with this change in energy is $F = -\frac{\Delta U}{\Delta z} = S_ { la}2l$.

Comment: I understand, but there has to be an upward force balancing the weight of the solid body, right? In the book (please see the attachment), it is stated that this surface tension force is corresponding to liquid-air interface.

Comment: Can you please attach a diagram that area of liquid-air interface changes but liquid-solid and solid-air interface doesn't change, i am unable to imagine it? Also, pls explain how the vertical force associated actually acts on the solid. Like shouldn't it act on the liquid?

Comment: @PinkAura I don't have that option, sorry. My drawing skills are very bad. You can find relevant pictures on the web. For example, on this  [page](https://thenakedchemist.com/surfactant-surface-tension/) Case from your book corresponds to vertical direction of $F_S$.

Comment: Np , sorry to disturb you again, but i think as liquid-air interface area changes(decreases), solid-liquid interface area increases and solid-air interface area decreases as well?
Also, pls address my second question (which is actually my doubt).

Comment: @PinkAura just try to imagine it. How is it that the contact area of solid-air and solid-liquid does not change, but the contact area of air-liquid changes. The second question is about the force acting on the liquid? Yes, there is a force acting on the liquid, but the liquid is in equilibrium because the solid is also acting on it. And liquid acts on a solid.

Comment: i would need to look at a microscopic diagram lol, to really understand this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Gec is excellent and helped me understand things as I too had the same doubt, as to why is it S(la) instead of S(ls) along with other doubts.

But let me try to explain what I understand.

Consider the pre initial stage of the experiment to determine the surface tention of water and air interface

The whole area "A" of the water surface is exposed to air and let the surface energy at this point be U(0).

U(0)= S(la)*A.
{S(la) is the surface tension of liquid air interface}

Next we introduce a thin vertical glass plate with negligible width, the water comes in contact with the "L" length of glass plate.

The surface energy U(1) at this stage will be

U(1)= S(la)*[A-L] + S(ls)*L

{S(ls) = surface tension of liquid solid interface}

As now L length of glass is covering the area of water and this area is not exposed to air anymore.

Next when the glass plate is pulled up due to the load "Mg" the LIQUID RISES UP WITH THE GLASS PLATE due to adhesion by "dX" height.
THIS RISE IN WATER LEVEL CAUSES THE RISE IN THE SURFACE AREA EXPOSED TO AIR. I have attached a diagram as well.

[image]

Therefore the new surface energy U(2) becomes

U(2)= U(1) + S(la)*[2(L*dX)]

Factor of 2 comes from the fact that there will be 2 sides of the dX*L area.

Now this increase in surface energy will be supplied by the work done by the force Mg
i.e.

U(2)-U(1)= S(la)*[2(L*dX)] ------(1)

Work done due to mass M under g for dX distance= Mg*dX

U(2)-U(1)= Mg*dX ---------(2)

From (1) and (2)

S(la)*[2(L*dX)]=Mg*dX

Dividing both sides by dX, we get

S(la)=Mg/2L

The fact that glass and water in contact
area remains same is because the weight we consider is just the weight at which it just seperates, i.e., the last weight which it could support without detaching.

Similarly the air and glass area also remains same.
It's just the water and air interface area that increases due the the rise in height of the water due to adhesion to glass.

At last weight mg which it can support the surface energy should be equal or less than the S(0), i.e. the pure S(la)*A. Beyond this weight the surface area energy due to further increase in area and its exposure to air would become more than the energy S(la)*A or U(0) and the water would want to go back to lower energy state and get separated from glass plate to make a smooth surface area A.

So you are somewhat right in saying that it is not "JUST" the liquid-air interface surface tension force responsible for the equilibrium of the solid kept on the surface of a liquid,
BUT IT IS THE TOTAL ENERGY OF THE SURFACE WHICH IS RESPONSIBLE.

Good way to see it is that we are not considering the adhesion forces of water with glass but the TOTAL ENERGY of water surface.

Hope this helps.